# Increment in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

I m coding in Pine Script and I am trying to increase the variable "`count`" by 1 when a logical test is confirmed "`close >= open`", so I try to use the following code:

```
var count = 0
if close >= open
    count := count + 1
plot(count)
```

When I try to save it I get the following error msg:

```
"no viable alternative at input 'count'"
```

If I try to remove the "`var`" in front of the count, always 0 is plotted in the chart.

Any ideas where the problem is?
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are certainly using the `v2` version of Pinescript, make sure that you are using `//@version=4`.

You can also use the following form:

```
count = cum(close >= open ? 1 : 0)
```